# START where both path and filename have spaces

Tags: batch-file

```
START /high /d "./files" "Program Name.exe"
```

This doesn't work, it works if "Program Name" wasn't in quotation marks, but in this scenario i don't have control over the file name and where the batch file gets executed. How would i solve this using Batch?

Comment: This is because the `start` command treats the first quoted argument as the Console title, provided that the quoted argument does not belong to any of the command line switches. You can provide a dummy title(or an empty one) to not interfere with the quoted executable name: `START "title" /high /d "./files" "Program Name.exe"`

Comment: This worked, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it's not *explicitly* stated in the help text from `start /?`:

```
START ["title"] [/D path] ...
```

the first quoted option is treated as the title for the window. In your case, that's the (supposed) executable name.

You can see that if you create an `x y.cmd` file containing only the command `@dir`, then run:

```
start /d "\program files" "\path\to\x y.cmd"
```

The directory `\path\to` above is the directory where you created it, needed because you'll actually be in the `program files` directory when you try to run it.

What you'll see is *not* a directory listing (because the script isn't running), but a new `cmd` window *titled* `\path\to\x y.cmd`.

If you instead use:

```
start "xyzzy" /d "\program files" "\path\to\x y.cmd"
```

you'll find that it *does* run the script, giving you a directory in a window titled `xyzzy`.

In other words, if you want to quote your program name, you should provide an *actual* title so there's no confusion.